# How to replace an image in a comment section from a third party application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, css-selectors

I need to replace an image in the comment section on my website. The comment section is on a separate server(third party application) and I don't have access to it.

The comment provider HTML Comment Box added images and it worked for 6 months before the images became 404 on their part.

I want to replace the broken image with an image of my own from my server.

I tried

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("comment_14368294")[0].src = "team-conasuaga-east-cowpen-trail-4_480px.jpg";
});
</script>
```

but didn't work.

The third party code I want to manipulate revealed from Chrome Inspector

```
<div class="comment" id="comment_14368294">
    <span class="date">(Apr 7, 2019) </span>
    <span class="author hcb-mod"><b class="author-name">Conrad Easley (mod) 
    </b>said:</span>
    <blockquote>
    <img align="left" class="gravatar"
    src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2484aca7544b9b228bbd67c0be236137?      
s=40&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fhtmlcommentbox.com%2Fstatic%2Fimages%2Fgravatar.png">
    Team Conasauga Workday on East Cowpen Trail April 6th, 2019 
    </blockquote>                   
    <a href="https://www.htmlcommentbox.com/storage/lg_14368294_team-conasuaga-east-cowpen-trail-4_480px.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.htmlcommentbox.com/storage/14368294_team-conasuaga-east-cowpen-trail-4_480px.jpg">
    </a>
    <p class="hcb-comment-tb">
    <a class="hcb-flag" href="javascript:hcb.flag('14368294')">
    <img src="https://www.htmlcommentbox.com/static/images/flag.png">flag
    </a> 
    <a class="hcb-like" href="javascript:hcb.like('14368294')">
    <img src="https://www.htmlcommentbox.com/static/images/like.png">like</a> 
    </p>
    <div class="likes" style="display:none">
    <span>0 </span>
    <img src="https://www.htmlcommentbox.com/static/images/like.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I ended up replacing the image with CSS using pseudo selectors

Basically, ::before and ::after only apply when the image fails to load. You can use absolute positioning to place the CSS pseudo element over the broken image placeholder:

```
#comment_14368294 img {
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

  #comment_14368294 img::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        line-height: 200px;
        background-color: #fd0;
        background: url(https://cohuttawildernesshiking.com/team-conasuaga-east-cowpen-trail-4_480px.jpg) no-repeat;
        color: currentColor;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 2px;
        display: block;
        width: 480px;
        height: 360px;
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with all the information we need to answer your question. Show us how the code is implemented. Is it an iframe? Is it loaded through Ajax? Keep in mind that your question will most likely be read by future users and they won't be able to tell what's going on if your website is no longer available or completely changed over time. Your question should contain everything we need in order to answer it without the need of visiting some external website.

Comment: It won't allow me to add the code since I don't have 10 posts. The code includes an image.

Comment: It's not an iframe. Assume it is Ajax.

Comment: Yes, it will allow you to add code. Don't try to screenshot your code. Just add the code itself and make sure each line of code has 4+ spaces in front of it so Stack Overflow recognises it as code. If you must add an image, just provide a link towards the image. Users with more reputation will review the image and edit your question for you so the image gets displayed.

Comment: As you can see, I've just edited your question for you so the line of code becomes readable. It works the same way :)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I have added the code from the third party application that shows up on Chrome Inspector. This is the code I want to manipulate or change. I am a hobbyist only.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can select the container that holds your comments and query for the first element that makes the comment unique. 
You can then ierate the array you get and change the image. The only issue you will be dealing with then is if you want to apply the same image or something unique.

I created this example for you. The comments container is the element that you provide on your own website to place all the comments in.
From there the first div is what makes the comment unique. In the example I replaced the different image with a similar cat one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var comments = $("#comments-container").find("div");

  //console.log(comments);

  $(comments).each(function(i, item) {

    // console.log(item);

    $(item).find('img').attr('src', 'https://loremflickr.com/220/200/cat');

  });


});
```

```css
#comments-container>div {
  margin: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='comments-container'>


  <div id="comment_1">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog" />
  </div>
  <div id="comment_2">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/girl" />
  </div>
  <div id="comment_3">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/boat" />
  </div>
  <div id="comment_4">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/statue" />
  </div>
  <div id="comment_5">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/guitar" />
  </div>



</div>
```

").find('img')
      .attr('src','steam-conasuaga-east-cowpen-trail-4_480px.jpg');

Why you apply the array in your code is not quite clear. Normally an `id` is only used once in a document. The getElementById() would not result in an array.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. The id was generated by the third party application. It's my website on my server but a third party comment section.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElement**s**ById is not a function. I presume you wanted to call getElementByid, and it returns only a node and not an array. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("comment_14368294").firstChild.src = "team-conasuaga-east-cowpen-trail-4_480px.jpg";
```

Comment: Yes, I had typed Elements which was wrong. I tried the solution you provided. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to change the path of the image **only when it fails to load**. I will suggest binding the **onerror event** to all images.

Below code will check all **image error event** and reset the path with your default image path if it **fails to load**.

```
$(function(){   
    $(window).load("load",function(e){  
        var defImg = "default img url"; // Default image path
        $(".comment").find("img").bind("error",function(){
            $(this).attr("src",defImg);
        }); 
    })

})
```

I have use **$window.load()** to bind my event because as per your question you are using the third party for comment module. It might be some cases when your third party has not completed its rendering before ready event fires.

Hope it will help and apologies for my grammar.